# Full Text Search in SQL 2000 installed on Windows Server 2008

Tags: full-text-search, sql-server-2000, windows-server-2008-r2

I've had developed a website many years ago using .NET 1 and SQL 2000! Recently, hosting provider for the site has moved to new server (Windows 2008 R2). SQL 2000 has been installed on the server and everythign seems to be OK.

After a while, my old client called me for a problem on searching in the site. I've checked it. I've activated Full Text feature on SQL 2000 for my database.

Here is the site address and you can check the search box:
http://www.iagh.org/

Here is the error:
Search on full-text catalog 'Portaj' for database ID 37, table ID 1171535257 with search condition '"*test*"' failed with unknown result (8004110a).

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2010/01/08/important-sql-server-and-windows-end-of-support-dates-you-should-know-about.aspx)

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/MS-SQL-Server/Q_26257679.html